# Spreadsheet Cell note is added twice -- duplicate text entered by script and meant to add

Tags: google-apps-script

Every time a cell is modified, I want to append a time stamp in the notes, along with who modified it.  I have the script working "On Edit" -- but it's adding the same note twice.

Sometimes, it adds it once.. but very commonly it adds the same note twice.

I've tried to change the variable name

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var comments = cell.getNote();
  comments = comments + "Mod: " + time+" by: "+username+" ;   "+'\n';
  cell.setNote(comments);
```

This is an OnEdit trigger.
I would expect it to just append a new line to the cell note.  It often appends two identical new lines.

ACTUAL:
For example, I edited a cell ONCE and the note shows.

Mod: Mon 05-20-19 @ 04:36 PM by: username ;
Mod: Mon 05-20-19 @ 04:36 PM by: username ;

EXPECTED:
I edit a cell ONCE and the note shows:
Mod: Mon 05-20-19 @ 04:36 PM by: username ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### About your situation:

From your situation, I thought you might be using `onEdit()` as the function name and the function might be installed as the OnEdit event trigger.

If my understanding is correct, the function is run 2 times by the simple trigger and the installable trigger. If you want to run only one time, please modify as follows.

#### Modification points:

- Uninstall the OnEdit event trigger of `onEdit()`.

  - By this, the function of `onEdit()` is run as the simple trigger.

Or

- If your script includes the methods which are required to be authorized, rename the function name from `onEdit()` to other name, and then, install the OnEdit event trigger, again.

  - By this, the function is run as the installable trigger.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Asynchronous Processing using Event Triggers](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)

If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: That is exactly how it is setup.. "OnEdit" is the function name.  I will try to change the function name.

Comment: THANKS! Changing the function name seems to have worked!

Comment: @B D Welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved.